# Display evaluated formula with entered values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help to script the function which will evaluate a formula.

Example:

```
Cell A1 = 1
Cell B1 = 2
Cell C1 = A1 + B1, which displays the sum of two numbers = 3
Cell D1 `= 1 + 2, which displays above formula with entered values
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I have found only script which takes the formula and display it as it is without entered values in formula parameters, i.e. `= A1 + B1

```
function GETFORMULA(reference) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  return range.getFormula();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it! Formula evaluation script is ready:

```
function eval(reference) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var commandFormula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var commandFormulaArgs = commandFormula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
    var commandFormulaRange = sheet.getRange(commandFormulaArgs[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }

  var calcFormula = commandFormulaRange.getFormula();
  var calcFormulaArgs = calcFormula.match(/(\w+)/gi);

  for(var i in calcFormulaArgs){
    try {
      calcFormula = calcFormula.replace(calcFormulaArgs[i], " " + sheet.getRange(calcFormulaArgs[i]).getValue() + " ");
    }
    catch(e) {
      throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
    }
  }

  return calcFormula;
}
```

Script replaces all cell references on actual cell values.